# DDD Entity Framework Repository Return Complex Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

I have a repository called LeadRepository that returns a model called Lead which is a person.

The UI I have is a dashboard that displays the following stats. They are all leads but in different states.

Total Leads: 52

Assigned: 49

Unassigned: 3

Contacted: 49

Uncontacted: 0

I am using a stored procedure to query the db. So i'm not using lazy loading to work out the count on the fly.

I have thought about two possible solutions below but neither of them feel quite right.

1. Use LeadRepository but have a method on it called GetStats() that returns a complex type. This does not have any association with the agg root Lead. Just a bunch of properties that have the different counts.
2. Create a LeadStatsRepository but this is not really an aggregate root as it has no id. It just is a grouped set of data.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Repositories are for aggregate roots. What you're after are read models and dedicated query objects.

Comment: Would I need to create a LeadQuery class that has a method called GetStats() which contains my query? So i'm bascially calling my query class that returns my read model instead of a repository class that returns the agg root?

Comment: Depends on your taste. The import bit is that you move querying away from the repositories and aggregate roots. I use Query objects like GetLeadStatisitcs that get handle by an implementation of IHandleQuery<ReadModel, GetLeadStatistics>.

Comment: This post made me write a more detailed explanation on my blog: http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/01/repositories-where-did-we-go-wrong_26.html

Answer (score 1):

Stats are best handled through a Service.  From Evans’ DDD, a good Service has these characteristics:

- The operation relates to a domain concept that is not a natural part of an Entity or Value Object
- The interface is defined in terms of other elements in the domain model
- The operation is stateless

Stats are a related to a domain object, but not really a part of the entity or value object.  They may not be defined in terms of other elements, but it's a possibility.  There isn't any state with stats, even keeping them over time isn't truly stateful.

Comment: I have a service called LeadService at the moment which is an application service. I didn't want to use the following like LeadRepository.GetTotal() and LeadRepository.GetAllAssigned() in the same service method because it would fire off multiple queries to the DB. This is why I had created a stored procedure to fire off 1 query. With your comment did you mean an application service or a domain service?